# Convert HttpResponse to byte array

Tags: java, http, sockets

I have

```
 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
```

my method can transfer byte[] over sockets on device and PC, so how can i convert HttpResponse into byte[] and than back to HttpResponse?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not easy.

If you simply wanted the body of the response, then you could do this to grab it

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    response.getEntity().writeTo(baos);
    byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

Alternatively:

```
    byte[] bytes = EntityUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity());
```

Then you could add the content to another `HttpResponse` object as follows:

```
    HttpResponse response = ...
    response.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(bytes));
```

---

But that's probably not good enough because you most likely need all of the other stuff in the original response; e.g. the status line and the headers (including the original content type and length).

If you want to deal with the whole response, you appear to have two choices:

- You could pick the response apart (e.g. getting the status line, iterating the headers) and manually serialize, then do the reverse at the other end.
- You can use `HttpResponseWriter` to do the serializing and `HttpResponseParser` to rebuild the response at the other end.  This is explained [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/tutorial/html/advanced.html).

Answer (score 1):

With java11:

```
var client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();
var request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(URI.create("https://yourdomain.test")).GET().build();
HttpResponse<byte[]> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofByteArray());
if (200 == response.statusCode()) {
            byte[] bytes = response.body();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to get it as a stream: `response.getEntity().getContent()`

then you can directly read the stream into a `byte[]`.

Comment: Thank you with it i find good method (EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity)), but there is still problem to convert byte[] in HttpEntity.